# auto-indexing in graphenedb

Tags: node.js, neo4j

How do I enable and configure node auto-indexing in a graphenedb 1.9.3 neo4j instance? I don't think I have access to the neo4j.properties file. Should I do this work in the application?

Thanks,

Eddie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

auto-indexes are now fully supported in [GrapheneDB](http://www.graphenedb.com/). You can configure the auto-index settings through the UI.

Answer (score 0):

GrapheneDB does not yet provide auto-indexing, but the feature is on its way..

GrapheneDB ‏@GrapheneDB 14m
@logpath You can't configure auto-indexing at the moment. We're working on it and expect to have it ready in a few weeks.

@logpath You can use custom indexes.